# My Vb program freezes once I press a button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I have a button on my user interface and once I press it the program freezes, and sometimes crashes.

I was hoping it would count the number of times a button is pressed and put it in a list box, and once it reaches 100 the loop would end. Instead it freezes, also Im not getting any errors.

[image]

Comment: Tour program is stuced in to infinite loop as clickCount value remains 1, It's not incrementing.

Comment: Can you please share what you want tot achive through the loop.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn what is expected of a question here. For one thing, you need to post code as text, formatted as code. We can't copy your code from a picture in order to test it. Furthermore, you need to have debugged your code before posting. If you had done that then you'd have seen what the problem is for yourself. There shouldn't be any loop. Loops are for performing an action multiple times. You want to perform that action only once per `Click` event.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll be sure to post correctly next time too.

Comment: May I know if your problem solved by the answers?
After my testing, the code in the answer below should solve your problem.
If solved, you could accept the helpful answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are stuck into the loop "Do Until".
An alternative could be to use this intead

```
lstData.Items.Add(clickCount)
picClick.Visible = (clickCount >= 100)
```

(Thanks to @jmcilhinney)

Comment: More simply, `picClick.Visible = (clickCount >= 100)`.